# Thunderbolt 3 connecting to USB 3.1

Tags: usb, usb-c, thunderbolt

I know that Thunderbolt 3 uses the USB Type-C port, and I know that you can plug a USB cable into a Thunderbolt port and it will function as USB or Thunderbolt depending on the peripheral.

However, if I have a USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C Port and I plug a Thunderbolt 3 peripheral into it, will I get the 10 Gbps from USB 3.1 Gen 2, or will I get a slower speed. Or, will it just not work at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB 3 is a subset of Thunderbolt 3 host. So if a USB 3.1 device is plugged into TB3 port, it works.

The opposite is not true. A TB3 device doesn't work in USB 3.1 host port. Charge function might work, but [data connection will be refused](https://www.pcmag.com/article/335277/what-thunderbolt-3-means-for-pc-connectivity-an-explainer).